# For /f loop process filename ampersand symbol

Tags: windows, batch-file, parameters, filenames

I have a for loop that processes dropped file(s), but I have recently come across a file whose filename includes `&` and I get an error of `& was unexpected at this time`. So I am not sure why it's doing it, I have it enclosed in quotes.

Filename example: `[This_&_That]_FileName.txt`

Small example:

```
FOR /F "tokens=* delims=;" %%P in ("%*") do call :LOOP %%P

:LOOP

if '%1'=='' goto :endloop

echo %1

pause

....

:endloop

exit
```

This works fine with spaces, but with the `&` symbol it crashes. I have to run the .bat file from `cmd` with the file name as an argument just to see the error.

I have tried enabling delayedexpansion - like in this post and either I didn't do it correctly or it just doesn't work for me: [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5744662/how-to-handle-ampersands-when-finding-replacing-text-in-batch-file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Windows Explorer bug

If a file name does **not** contain a space character, the explorer doesn't surround it by double quotes for *drag & drop* actions. As a consequence you can not treat such file names with an ampersand (`&`) correctly in a batch file.
Assume, you have the following batch `script.bat`:

```
@ECHO Off &SETLOCAL
:loop
ECHO "%~1"
SHIFT /1
IF NOT "%~1"=="" GOTO :loop
pause
```

Make two files, eg. on the command line:

```
type nul>"This_&_That.txt"
type nul>"This & That.txt"
```

Now go to the explorer, drag the two files and drop it at your `script.bat`.
Let's see, what happens:

```
"C:\TEST\This & That.txt"
"C:\TEST\This_"
press any key to continue . . .
```

[Extended explanation.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8550398/2098699)

Comment: thanks but the for statement is still not passing the correct name to the subroutine, it is still cutting off at the "&" symbol

Comment: maybe but I am not sure how to apply all of that....as 1, its not going to just be a .txt or .csv file, it is also for 1 or multiple files that I am dropping on the the bat file as to why I am using a /f %*., so how can I implement that so that i can drag and drop any file and it will pass the filename with or without an & symbol to the subroutine

Comment: here is a picture of it not working, the test.bat is on my desktop, had have dropped the file from the location shown in the results,[link]http://i.snag.gy/fnGBj.jpg

Comment: wow - didn't even occur to me that there would be such a bug - thanks for finding guess i'll just have to rename the files. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the subroutine :LOOP.  Can you live with the quotes around %%P?

```
FOR /F "tokens=* delims=;" %%P in ("%*") do echo."%%P" & pause
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I think I need the sub routine as I am not just printing out the file name...it was just a substitute for here....but I dont care about quotes as long as it works. And if I echo my current %1 (file with no &) the path and file already has quotes around it...which is what i thought the quotes around the %* was doing.  so putting quotes around the %%P would not add another set of quotes and make it unreadable?

Comment: Yea adding quotes around %%P seems to almost void the quotes around %* and isn't able to process paths / filenames with spaces.

Comment: Could you post what you have?  I don't know what you are using now (my code without the subroutine or yours with it).

Comment: I think if you echo.%%P instead of calling :LOOP yoou will see that it does not have quotes.

Comment: I am using the sub:   FOR /F "tokens=* delims=;" %%P in ("%*") do call :LOOP %%P

:LOOP

if "%1"=="" goto :endloop
REM ----VARS-----
set "f=%~n1"
set fn=%f: =_%
set var=%tempd%\%fn%_new.txt
set var2=%tempd%\%fn%_new2.txt

echo "%1"
echo.
echo %var%
echo.
echo %var2%
pause  this is some but in continues on

Comment: Ok yes...even by doing this  FOR /F "tokens=* delims=;" %%P in ("%*") do echo."%%P" & pause results are  "drive\path\\[This_" so it is not processing the full filename to the sub

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
if '%1'=='' goto :endloop
```

the value of `%1` is NOT enclosed in quotes, but in apostrophes. Change it this way:

```
if "%1"=="" goto :endloop
```

Of course, you also need to enclose `%1` in quotes in the `echo` command in the subroutine AND around `%%P` in the calling program, but in this case , the value of `%1` woud have the quotes already

Comment: Thanks - stupid mis, but that solves the error...but the processed filename using the above example and echo %1 results:  drive\path\\[This_

Comment: and echoing "%1" results in "drive\path\\[This_"

Comment: Like i said above putting %1 in quotes in the subroutine still results in the filename from being fully prcessed, it stops at where the & symbol is.

Comment: @Aacini the term should be "%~1" in case the filename is quoted.

Comment: @foxidrive: Not exactly. If %%P is enclosed in quotes this way: `call :LOOP "%%P"`, then `%1` is always enclosed in quotes and `%~1` is not, so the program should use the version it needs in each case. However, no one modification solves this problem as Endoro explained in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmmm.... since I THINK you are we using your code with subroutine... I will ignore the comment about my single line suggestion w/o CALL.  We should pick one problem and solve that rather than bounce back and forth.  In your example you need to quote the %%P.  Typical practice in the subroutine is to do "%~1".  The tilde removes quotes and the "" puts them back again if needed.  Sometimes they are not needed, but in your case they are needed.  Your CALL uses :LOOP and your example used :ENCODE.  I will revert to :LOOP.

```
FOR /F "tokens=* delims=;" %%P in ("%*") do call :LOOP "%%P"

:LOOP
if "%~1"=="" goto :endloop
REM ----VARS-----
set "f=%~n1"
set fn=%f: =_%
set var=%tempd%\%fn%_new.txt
set var2=%tempd%\%fn%_new2.txt
echo "%~1"
echo.
echo %var%
echo.
echo %var2%
pause
REM this is some but in continues on
echo.done & PAUSE
```

Comment: Nope... Still by dropping lets say C:\Users\Jim\Desktop\Folder\\[This_&_That]_FileName.txt onto the bat file, results with from the exact code above, "C:\Users\Jim\Desktop\Folder\\[This_"  "C:\Users\Jim\Desktop\Folder\tempd"\\[This__new.txt "C:\Users\Jim\Desktop\Folder\tempd"\\[This__new2.txt Press any key to continue...

Comment: Ahhh... you need quotes for the other 3 SET commands.  set "fn=%f: =_%"    
    set "var=%tempd%\%fn%_new.txt"
    set "var2=%tempd%\%fn%_new2.txt"

Comment: well im not to worried about those, at the moment, as the echo "%~1" is incorrect, meaning those will be incorrect no matter what. but thanks that will probably solve a future issue